# How to add the name of the supervisor in a @thesis field?

Tags: biblatex

In the `biblatex` doc, it says ( Version 1.7, p.11):

> thesis
>
> A thesis written for an educational institution to satisfy the
>   requirements for a degree. Use the type field to specify the type of
>   thesis.
>
> Required fields: author, title, type, institution, year/date
>
> Optional fields: subtitle, titleaddon, language, note, location,
>   month, isbn, chapter, pages, pagetotal, addendum, pubstate, doi,
>   eprint, eprintclass, eprinttype, url, urldate

I would like to know if there is any "canonical" way to add the name of the supervisor(s) in a field of the `.bib` file (no `.bbl` manipulation please, I want my bibliography to be usable "as it" in several documents).

The expect result could be something like  :

> Meand Myself. “A brilliant result, explained”. PhD thesis**, under the
>   joint supervision of Pr. Toto and Pr. Tata**. Université Paris 24,
>   Nov. 2013.

The "under the (joint) supervision" could be a string that would be declined in four ways:

- under the supervision of
- under the joint supervision of
- and the abridged forms

Comment: I guess this is really a 'library science' issue: the supervisor isn't normally regarded as part of the bibliographic record here (they supervised but didn't write the thesis, after all).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By default, `biblatex` does not seem to support a supervisor, so some changes have to be made, but we can keep these changes to a minimum.

Firstly, we define the new name list `supervisor` via a new datamodel (`thesis.dbx`)

```
\ProvidesFile{thesis.dbx}[2014/06/14 supervisor for theses]
\RequireBiber[3]
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=list,datatype=name]{supervisor}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[thesis]{supervisor}
```

Save the lines above in a file called `thesis.dbx` and put it somewhere LaTeX can find it.
In the MWE below, this is done automatically via `filecontents`.

The datamodel needs to be loaded via the `datamodel` option (`datamodel=thesis`, e.g. `\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber,datamodel=thesis]{biblatex}`).

Secondly, we need to declare the new strings you asked for in an `.lbx` file (the file should be called `english-thesis.lbx`)

```
  \ProvidesFile{english-thesis.lbx}[2014/06/14 english for thesis]
  \InheritBibliographyExtras{english}
  \NewBibliographyString{supervision,jointsupervision}
  \DeclareBibliographyStrings{%
    inherit           = {english},
    supervision       = {{under the supervision of}{under sup\adddotspace of}},
    jointsupervision  = {{under the joint supervision of}{under joint sup\adddotspace of}},
  }
```

Make sure to save the file somewhere LaTeX can find it (as above: in the MWE below, the file is created with `filecontents`).

We then employ this language variant via `\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-thesis}`.

Finally, we define a new bibmacro

```
\newbibmacro*{thesissupervisor}{%
  \ifnameundef{supervisor}{}{%
    \ifnumgreater{\value{supervisor}}{1}
      {\bibstring{jointsupervision}}
      {\bibstring{supervision}}
    \printnames{supervisor}}}
```

that prints the supervisor and the introducing string depending on the number of supervisors.

We then patch the `@thesis` driver to use our new macro (that is done with the awesome [`xpatch`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xpatch) package).

```
\xpatchbibdriver{thesis}
  {\printfield{type}}
  {\printfield{type}
   \newunit
   \usebibmacro{thesissupervisor}}
  {\typeout{yep}}
  {\typeout{no}}
```

The supervisor is now simply added to the `supervisor` field like so

```
@thesis{geer,
  author       = {de Geer, Ingrid},
  title        = {Earl, Saint, Bishop, Skald~-- and Music},
  type         = {phdthesis},
  institution  = {Uppsala Universitet},
  date         = 1985,
  subtitle     = {The Orkney Earldom of the Twelfth Century. A Musicological
                  Study},
  location     = {Uppsala},
  supervisor   = {James Oint and Stan Upervisor},
}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[british,12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@thesis{geer,
  author       = {de Geer, Ingrid},
  title        = {Earl, Saint, Bishop, Skald~-- and Music},
  type         = {phdthesis},
  institution  = {Uppsala Universitet},
  date         = 1985,
  subtitle     = {The Orkney Earldom of the Twelfth Century. A Musicological
                  Study},
  location     = {Uppsala},
  supervisor   = {James Oint and Stan Upervisor},
}

@thesis{loh,
  author       = {Loh, Nin C.},
  title        = {High-Resolution Micromachined Interferometric Accelerometer},
  type         = {mathesis},
  institution  = {Massachusetts Institute of Technology},
  date         = 1992,
  location     = {Cambridge, Mass.},
  supervisor   = {Stan Upervisor},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber,datamodel=thesis]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents*}{thesis.dbx}
  \ProvidesFile{thesis.dbx}[2014/06/14 supervisor for theses]
  \RequireBiber[3]
  \DeclareDatamodelFields[type=list,datatype=name]{supervisor}
  \DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[thesis]{supervisor}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{english-thesis.lbx}
  \ProvidesFile{english-thesis.lbx}[2014/06/14 english for thesis]
  \InheritBibliographyExtras{english}
  \NewBibliographyString{supervision,jointsupervision}
  \DeclareBibliographyStrings{%
    inherit           = {english},
    supervision       = {{under the supervision of}{under sup\adddotspace of}},
    jointsupervision  = {{under the joint supervision of}{under joint sup\adddotspace of}},
  }
\end{filecontents*}

\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-thesis}

\newbibmacro*{thesissupervisor}{%
  \ifnameundef{supervisor}{}{%
    \ifnumgreater{\value{supervisor}}{1}
      {\bibstring{jointsupervision}}
      {\bibstring{supervision}}
    \printnames{supervisor}}}

\xpatchbibdriver{thesis}
  {\printfield{type}}
  {\printfield{type}
   \newunit
   \usebibmacro{thesissupervisor}}
  {\typeout{yep}}
  {\typeout{no}}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\nocite{*}
\begin{document}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you cannot create the new name list `supervisor`, you could try and abuse the `editor` field, then there is no need for the `.dbx` file.
This solution should work with BibTeX as well.

The macros `thesissupervisor` becomes

```
\newbibmacro*{thesissupervisor}{%
  \ifnameundef{editor}{}{%
    \ifnumgreater{\value{editor}}{1}
      {\bibstring{jointsupervision}}
      {\bibstring{supervision}}
    \printnames{editor}}}
```

You then give the supervisor in the `editor` field in the bib entry like so

```
@thesis{geer,
  author       = {de Geer, Ingrid},
  title        = {Earl, Saint, Bishop, Skald~-- and Music},
  type         = {phdthesis},
  institution  = {Uppsala Universitet},
  date         = 1985,
  subtitle     = {The Orkney Earldom of the Twelfth Century. A Musicological
                  Study},
  location     = {Uppsala},
  editor       = {James Oint and Stan Upervisor},
}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[british,12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@thesis{geer,
  author       = {de Geer, Ingrid},
  title        = {Earl, Saint, Bishop, Skald~-- and Music},
  type         = {phdthesis},
  institution  = {Uppsala Universitet},
  date         = 1985,
  subtitle     = {The Orkney Earldom of the Twelfth Century. A Musicological
                  Study},
  location     = {Uppsala},
  editor       = {James Oint and Stan Upervisor},
}

@thesis{loh,
  author       = {Loh, Nin C.},
  title        = {High-Resolution Micromachined Interferometric Accelerometer},
  type         = {mathesis},
  institution  = {Massachusetts Institute of Technology},
  date         = 1992,
  location     = {Cambridge, Mass.},
  editor       = {Stan Upervisor},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{filecontents*}{english-thesis.lbx}
  \ProvidesFile{english-thesis.lbx}[2014/06/14 english for thesis]
  \InheritBibliographyExtras{english}
  \NewBibliographyString{supervision,jointsupervision}
  \DeclareBibliographyStrings{%
    inherit           = {english},
    supervision       = {{under the supervision of}{under sup\adddotspace of}},
    jointsupervision  = {{under the joint supervision of}{under joint sup\adddotspace of}},
  }
\end{filecontents*}

\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-thesis}

\newbibmacro*{thesissupervisor}{%
  \ifnameundef{editor}{}{%
    \ifnumgreater{\value{editor}}{1}
      {\bibstring{jointsupervision}}
      {\bibstring{supervision}}
    \printnames{editor}}}

\xpatchbibdriver{thesis}
  {\printfield{type}}
  {\printfield{type}
   \newunit
   \usebibmacro{thesissupervisor}}
  {\typeout{yep}}
  {\typeout{no}}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\nocite{*}
\begin{document}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for this clear, documented and efficient solution. Unfortunately, I cannot test it yet, for my version of biblatex (1.7) seems too old. Is it compatible with the bibtex backend as well ?

Comment: @Clément Version 1.7 is indeed very old (the current version is 2.9). The new name field `supervisor` cannot be created without Biber. You could try and abuse the `editor` field instead, that might work, but I'm not sure what capabilities your version of `biblatex` actually has.

Comment: @Clément I have added a solution that did work with BibTeX on my system, but I'm not sure whether it will work with your version of `biblatex`.

Comment: This second solution is brilliant, and it has a major advantage: the editor field is not printed in any style that I know for the `@thesis` field.