# Citing (author, journalabbr., year) needed

Tags: biblatex, citing

I am looking for a certain kind of citing in my thesis. Unfortunality there is no option in biblatex for my needs. Is the best thing to declare an new "short journal"-field in the bib file or does LaTex recognice the initials of the Journal?

I added a full minimal example to show what i am actually working wiht:

```
 \begin{filecontents}{min.bib}
    @article{boisson2003unexpected,
  title={Unexpected protein families including cell defense components feature in the N-myristoylome of a higher eukaryote},
  author={Boisson, B. and Giglione, Carmela and Meinnel, Thierry},
  journal={Journal of Biological Chemistry},
  year={2003},
  publisher={ASBMB}
}
\end{filecontents}
```

\documentclass[fontsize=11pt, paper=a4, ngerman, DIV=calc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[%style=authoryear-comp,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,isbn=false,natbib=true, citestyle=authoryear,bibstyle=authoryear,backend=biber,maxnames=1,maxcitenames=1]
{biblatex}
\addbibresource{min.bib}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{
   andothers = {{et\,al\adddot}}            }

\begin{document}

\citep{boisson2003unexpected}
\[1em]
How it should look like:
\[1em]
(Boisson et al., JBC, 2003)

\printbibliography

`\end{document}<code>`

Comment: There have been some discussions about abbreviated journal names before. [How to abbreviate journal name in citation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33441/35864) (the `biber` solution there is quite old, maybe use the one from the next link), [Show journal abbreviation in reference list with biblatex/biber](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/76241/35864), [Is there a transparent way to automatically abbreviate journal names?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111724/35864).

Comment: Of course LaTeX does not read through the journal field and magically replaces the journal name with the correct abbreviation. There are three ways I see here: (1) use the [`.bib` string method](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/111725/35864), this will require you to rework your database extensively though. (2) [Let `biblatex`/`biber` re-map journal names](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/76276/35864), you'll have feed `biblatex` the long and short versions, it will do the rest. (3) Create a new entry field and add the names yourself (or let `biblatex` map them).

Comment: You can find some questions on new data fields [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/131204/35864), [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/184878/35864), or [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65374/35864).

Comment: unfortunatly this is not what i need. i'm fine with my bibliography. i want to add a third field to the output of the citing command. like (Author, journal initials, year). and i have no idea how to declare it.

Comment: Well, you obviously need both to get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

First thing to do is to add a field for the journal abbreviation to the article entrytype, `journalabbr` in the MWE. Therefore you need to declare a datamodel (an extra file; in the MWE I've used filecontents to simulate that) and you have to tell biblatex/biber to use it in the package options.

Then you have to modify the cite command, so it fits your needs. `\citep` from the authoryear-style (your citestyle) uses the `\cite` command. There you just have to add a switch, which  checks if the field `journalabbr` is empty or not, and prints it out or not.

Last but not least you have to add the abbreviation fields to the entries.

MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents}{min.bib}
@article{boisson2003unexpected,
  title={Unexpected protein families including cell defense components feature in the N-myristoylome of a higher eukaryote},
  author={Boisson, B. and Giglione, Carmela and Meinnel, Thierry},
  journal={Journal of Biological Chemistry},
  journalabbr={JBC},
  year={2003},
  publisher={ASBMB}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{authorjabbryear.dbx}
\ProvidesFile{authorjabbryear.dbx}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{journalabbr}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[article]{journalabbr}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[fontsize=11pt, paper=a4, ngerman, DIV=calc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,isbn=false,natbib=true, citestyle=authoryear,bibstyle=authoryear,backend=biber,maxnames=1,maxcitenames=1,
,datamodel=authorjabbryear%added!
] {biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{ andothers = {{et\,al\adddot}} }

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%from authoryear.cbx
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{\addspace}}
       {\printnames{labelname}%
        \setunit{\nameyeardelim}}%
     \iffieldundef{journalabbr}{}{%
        \printfield{journalabbr}%
        \setunit{\nameyeardelim}%
        }%
     \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}

\addbibresource{min.bib}

\begin{document}

\citep{boisson2003unexpected} 

How it should look like: 

(Boisson et al., JBC, 2003)

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why don't you use the `shortjournal` field for the abbreviation? Then you wouldn't have to extend the datamodel.