# Add journal name to biblatex references

Tags: biblatex

I'm using biblatex in a beamer presentation so that I can use the \footcite command. The problem is that bibliography styles handling in biblatex don't look quite straighforward and none of the default styles will actually work for me since they do not show Journal references.

I'm looking for something similar as .bst files for Bibtex, since I can have JPC and PRL, PR bibliography styles. I surfed the internet and this stackexchange but couldn't find a proper solution. Could somebody provide me a working example with a style which shows: Authors, Year, Journal?

Best regards

The following code (authoryear style) does not show journal. Alphabetic, numeric etc only produces blank references.

[image: no journal info]
MWE:

```
\documentclass[8pt mathserif]{beamer}

\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{ae,aecompl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{library.bib}
\usetheme{Madrid}


\title[]{Title}
\author[]{author}
\institute{MSE @ NTU\\
The Zhao Research Group\\             

}
\date[]{Thursday 31, July 2014}

\begin{document}

\section{Review of interesting phenomenology}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks noframenumbering]{Polaron Transformation}

\begin{itemize}         

\item The original theory was  developed by Munn-Silbey{\tiny \footcite{Silbey1980}\footcite{Munn1985}\footcite{Munn1985a}} and further refined by Zhao et al. \footcite{JCP1994OntheMunn}\footcite{Chen2011} 

\end{itemize}   
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

And the library.bib file only contains entries such as the one referenced:

```
@article{Silbey1980,
author = {Silbey, R. and Munn, R. W.},
doi = {10.1063/1.439425},
file = {:Users/Caco/Documents/Mendeley Desktop/General theory of electronic transport in molecular crystals. I. Local linear electron–phonon coupling R. Silbey and R. W. Munn.pdf:pdf},
issn = {00219606},
journal = {The Journal of Chemical Physics},
number = {4},
pages = {2763},
title = {{General theory of electronic transport in molecular crystals. I. Local linear electron–phonon coupling}},
url = {http://scitation.aip.org/content/aip/journal/jcp/72/4/10.1063/1.439425},
volume = {72},
year = {1980}
}
```

Comment: From the top of my head i would say that all biblatex styles show the journal title. Can you provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) showing us the problem?

Comment: This may sound stupid, but without a bib-file, there will never be a journal title. Please add a minimal bib-file as well.

Comment: `\footfullcite`

Comment: It is easy to add a field to a cite command. See e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193142/citing-author-journalabbr-year-needed. Don't use the ae and aecompl package. Use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and install the cm-super fonts if this lead to "blurry" fonts.

Comment: I already added all requested information. \footfullcite will give me extremely long references, with DOI, title and so on. I just need to add the Journal, maybe in abbreviated form. Thanks

Comment: Ulrike Fischer I don't understand your answer. I cannot figure out how to add journal in biblatex style from that post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `authoryear`, you can just modify the `cite` macro a bit to include the journal reference via just the two following lines

```
\setunit{\addcomma\space}%
\usebibmacro{journal}
```

The original definition of the `cite` bibmacro can be found in [`authoryear.cbx` (ll. 10-18 in v3.14)](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/2ddd2836927d08ac600c8fa3af1897417548ac05/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/authoryear.cbx#L10-L18).

MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\usetheme{Madrid}


\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}
       {\printnames{labelname}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}%
     \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
     \usebibmacro{journal}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Polaron Transformation}

\begin{itemize}

\item The original theory was  developed by Munn-Silbey\footcite{cicero}\footcite{aksin}\footcite{angenendt}
  and further refined by Zhao et al.\footcite{bertram}\footcite{doody}

\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks moewe, that totally worked for me. Do you know how can I add the names of the authors? I'm only getting the last name.

Comment: @cacosomoza Certainly, you can replace `\printnames{labelname}%` in the macro above with `\printnames[first-last]{labelname}%` for "First Last" name order or with `\printnames[last-first]{labelname}%` for "Last, First" name order.

Comment: Thanks for this MWE, very useful! A follow up question, though: for entries of type *inproceedings* the modified cite command seems to not show the booktitle - any suggestions how to make this happen?

Comment: @DanielRuprecht You can add another `\setunit{\addcomma\space}%
     \usebibmacro{booktitle}` or so after the `\usebibmacro{journal}`. If you want something more sophisticated please consider asking a new question ideally linking back to this question and describing in more detail what exactly you need to get done.

Comment: That is just what I was looking for, thanks a lot for the quick answer!