# using title in citation only if bibliographic entry is of type "book"

Tags: biblatex

I am following moewe's solution for making an author-journal-year citation style, as described in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/194947/10127).

In the comments to that post, a solution is proposed for using the `booktitle` field of an `inproceedings` reference. How can one instead use the `title` field of a reference if and only if the reference is of type `book` (not `article`). I do not know the `if/then/else` syntax needed to determine if the reference is a `book`, which would conditionally control the following statements:

```
\setunit{\addcomma\space}%
\usebibmacro{title}%
```

The MWE of the linked post is reproduced below, with blank lines surrounding the above two lines which must be conditionally gated.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\usetheme{Madrid}


\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{\addspace}}
       {\printnames{labelname}%
        \setunit{\nameyeardelim}}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}%
     \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
     \usebibmacro{journal}}%
     %
     \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
      \usebibmacro{title}%
     %
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Polaron Transformation}

\begin{itemize}         

\item The original theory was  developed by Munn-Silbey{\tiny \footcite{cicero}\footcite{aksin}\footcite{angenendt}} and further refined by Zhao et al. \footcite{bertram}\footcite{doody} 

\end{itemize}   
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just a note of your MWE: You have added your `\setunit{\addcomma\space}\usebibmacro{title}` inbetween the `true` and `false` arguments of `\iffieldundef{shorthand}{<true>}{<false>}` (note the closing brace after `\usebibmacro{journal}` which is in the `true` argument. This gives you unexpected results.

Comment: @DavidPurton: Thanks for pointing that out. I hadn't noticed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are looking for `\ifentrytype{type}{true}{false}`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\usetheme{Madrid}


\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{\addspace}}
       {\printnames{labelname}%
        \setunit{\nameyeardelim}}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}%
     \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
     \usebibmacro{journal}%
     \ifentrytype{book}
      {\setunit{\addcomma\space}%
      \usebibmacro{title}}{}}%
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Polaron Transformation}

\begin{itemize}

\item The original theory was  developed by Munn-Silbey{\tiny \footcite{cicero}\footcite{aksin}\footcite{angenendt}} and further refined by Zhao et al. \footcite{bertram}\footcite{doody}

\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Note that the macro `cite:labelyear+extrayear` is deprecated, use `cite:labeldate+extradate` instead.