# Can't get a comma after a journal with dot in author-journal-year style

Tags: biblatex

[This post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/194078) shows how an author-year-journal citation style can be realized by minimal modification of the `\cite` macro.  I adapted the MWE from that post to create an author-journal-year style; however, the comma which should separate the journal from the year appears only if the journal name does not contain a terminal period.  Is it possible to add the comma regardless of any terminal punctuation?

The `\cite` macro is modified by adding the following three lines:

```
 \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
 \usebibmacro{journal}%
 \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
```

The complete MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\usetheme{Madrid}


\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{\addspace}}
       {\printnames{labelname}%
        \setunit{\nameyeardelim}}%
     \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
     \usebibmacro{journal}%
     \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}%
    }
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Polaron Transformation}

\begin{itemize}

\item The original theory was  developed by Munn-Silbey{\tiny \footcite{cicero}\footcite{aksin}\footcite{angenendt}} and further refined by Zhao et al. \footcite{bertram}\footcite{doody}

\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

It produces the following output:
[image]

As can be seen, the 3rd and 5th references include a comma between the journal and the year, while the 2nd and 4th do not.  I would like the 2nd, for example, to appear as "Aksin et al., J. Organomet. Chem., 2006.".

Separately, can the `\cite` macro be easily modified to place parentheses around the year?  In this case, the desired formatting of the 2nd reference would be "Aksin et al., J. Organomet. Chem. (2006).".

Comment: I suggest you ask about the second point (parentheses around the year) in a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my system (`biblatex` v3.14) I get the expected output

[image: Aksın et al., J. Organomet. Chem., 2006.]

It seems that you are running an older version of `biblatex` that doesn't yet add `\isdot` to the `journaltitle` format, see https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/851 for background.

Update your system if possible. If that is not possible,

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\mkbibemph{#1\isdot}}
```

should suffice as a workaround.

---

Note that I just updated my answer to [Add journal name to biblatex references](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/194078/35864) to avoid outdated bibmacros.

Comment: Thanks moewe, your suggested workaround resolved the issue with my version of biblatex.  I will attempt to update (I encountered unresolvable issues during my last [update attempt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/529891)).  As you suggested, I created a [second question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/540982) about parenthesizing the year.