# author-journal-(year) style for biblatex

Tags: biblatex

[This post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/540967) contains an MWE with an author-journal-year citation style for biblatex, adapted from an [author-year-journal](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/194947) citation style.  The MWE is copied below with a single modification, which removes the comma between the journal and the year.  Can the `\cite` macro in this MWE be easily modified to enclose the year in parentheses?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\usetheme{Madrid}


\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\mkbibemph{#1\isdot}}
\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{\addspace}}
       {\printnames{labelname}%
        \setunit{\nameyeardelim}}%
     \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
     \usebibmacro{journal}%
     \setunit{\space}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}%
    }
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Polaron Transformation}

\begin{itemize}

\item The original theory was  developed by Munn-Silbey{\tiny \footcite{cicero}\footcite{aksin}\footcite{angenendt}} and further refined by Zhao et al. \footcite{bertram}\footcite{doody}

\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Relevant output:
[image]

In the desired output, the 2nd and 5th references would be formatted as follows:

> Aksin et al., J. Organomet. Chem. (2006).
>
> Doody, The Journal of Narrative Technique (1974).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redefine the bibmacro `cite:labeldate+extradate` to add the parentheses. The original definition can be found in `authoryear.cbx` ([ll. 56-59 in v3.14](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/2ddd2836927d08ac600c8fa3af1897417548ac05/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/authoryear.cbx#L56-L59))

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\usetheme{Madrid}

% only needed in outdated biblatex versions,
% see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/540967/35864
%\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\mkbibemph{#1\isdot}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}}
       {\printnames{labelname}}%
     \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
     \usebibmacro{journal}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:labeldate+extradate}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
       \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
         \printlabeldateextra}}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Polaron Transformation}

\begin{itemize}
\item The original theory was  developed by Munn-Silbey\footcite{cicero}\footcite{aksin}\footcite{angenendt}
  and further refined by Zhao et al.\footcite{bertram}\footcite{doody}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: Aksın et al., J. Organomet. Chem. (2006).]

Comment: Thanks again, moewe.  By the way, I changed `\renewbibmacro*{cite:labeldate+extradate}` to `\renewbibmacro*{cite:labelyear+extrayear}` given my outdated biblatex version.  I tried once again to update to TeXLive 2020, but encountered the same problem (biber exiting 255), so it seems I am stuck at biblatex version 3.12 for the present.

Comment: @user001 `cite:labeldate+extradate` has been the correct name since `biblatex` v3.8 (2017-11-04), so with v3.12 you should use the new name `cite:labeldate+extradate`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  On a system with biblatex v3.4, I was seeing the error `! Package biblatex Error: Bibliography macro 'cite:labeldate+extradate' undefined`.  The `cite:labeldate+extradate` macro  is recognized on another system with biblatex v3.12.

Comment: @user001 Even with `biblatex` v3.4 the code as posted should not throw an error. It will produce a warning `Package biblatex Warning: Macro 'cite:labeldate+extradate' undefined. Using \newbibmacro on input line 22.` but that warning is benign. (Of course you will get an error in versions before v3.8 if you don't have a line (re)defining `cite:labeldate+extradate`.)

Comment: Indeed, I had encountered that error while testing your revised code in the author-year-journal [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/194947) with biblatex v3.4.  Upon finding that the date-->year substitution resolved the matter, I carried it over to this example as well.  Thanks.